# Bayesian probability on Bernoulli distribution

Tags: statistics, bayes-theorem

Let $D$ be a Bernoulli distribution with $P[X=1] = \theta$ (and so $P[X=0]=1-\theta$). Let $\chi = \{0,1\}$ be an iid sample drawn from $D$. Assume a prior distribution on $\theta$, with $\theta$ uniformly distributed between 0 and .25.

What is the value of $p(\theta)$ for $\theta=\frac{1}{8}$?What is the value of $p(\theta \vert \chi)$ for $\theta=\frac{1}{8}$?

I'm confused by what the question is asking for, and how everything ties together. There are other parts, but I think if I can grasp what's happening here I will be able to figure out the rest. I think I am supposed to be finding the probability that the random variable $\theta$ takes on the value of $\frac{1}{8}$ given that it is uniformly distributed over the interval [0,$\frac{1}{4}$], but isn't this probability 0 because the probability of choosing any given point in an interval is 0?

I know I must be thinking about this incorrectly because I should use Bayes' rule for the second part, and $p(\theta)$ should be interpreted as the prior probability of $\theta$, which definitely should not be 0.

This is a homework question, so I'm not looking for an explicit answer, but any hints would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it's natural that you're confused.

> What is the value of $p(\theta)$ for $\theta=\frac{1}{8}$?

is slightly confusing. First, as you rightly noted, $\theta$ is a continuous random variable, so $p(\theta)$ is actually a density function.

Then, let's guess that "value of $p(\theta)$ for $\theta=\frac{1}{8}$" simply amounts to evaluate $p(\theta)$ at that value [*]. In  that case, the value you'd get -let's call it $p_\theta( \frac{1}{8})$- is not a probability, it's just the value of a probability density.

True, the probability that $\theta$ takes that particular value is zero. But, it doesn't matter. What matters is that the probability that $\theta$ takes a value in a interval of length $h$ around that value is $p_\theta( \frac{1}{8}) h$ for small $h$. Because of this, it makes sense to compare this with the a posteriory value.

[*] Presumably, it's stated in that convoluted way because it would be even more confusing to write $p(\frac{1}{8})$ - this confusion is a consequence of the common abuse of notation of writing $p(x)$ and $p(y)$ to mean different density functions, we should write $p_X(x)$ , $p_Y(y)$  etc

Comment: Thank you! This makes a lot of sense--I didn't realize I was looking at a probability density instead of a regular probability.

Answer (score 1):

I think they just want the probability density. So in this case $p(\theta=\frac 18)=4$ because you are spreading the total amount of probaility, $1$, uniformly over an interval with length $\frac 14$. (Visualise a rectangle with base $\frac 14$, area $1$, and hence height $4$.)

For the second bit they again want the probability density, now for the cases where you condition on $\chi=0$ and $\chi=1$. I'll leave you to try to work this out with Bayes' rule.

Comment: Thank you! I definitely missed that I was looking for a probability density.

Comment: I've been thinking about the second part a lot, and I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong. Is there a difference between $p(\mathcal{X}|\theta)$ and $p(\mathcal{X})$ in this case? It seems like they are the same, because $X=0$ and $X=1$ are drawn from the Bernoulli distribution defined by $\theta$, so $p(X=1)=\theta$ and $p(X=1|\theta)=\theta$ too; I feel like I'm missing something here.

Comment: @steve The thing you're describing is $p(\chi|\theta)$. The number $p(\chi)$ is the probability of $\chi$ when you don't know what $\theta$ is. This means that it is the average of $p(\chi|\theta)$ weighted by your distribution $p(\theta)$. That is to say $p(\chi)=\int p(\chi|\theta)p(\theta)$. This is the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability).